# Block TCP-send till ACK returned

Tags: winapi, sockets, tcp, blocking

I am programming a client application sending TCP/IP packets to a server. Because of timeout issues I want to start a timer as soon as the ACK-Package is returned (so there can be no timeout while the package has not reached the server). I want to use the winapi.

Setting the Socket to blocking mode doesn't help, because the send command returns as soon as the data is written into the buffer (if I am not mistaken). Is there a way to block send till the ACK was returned, or is there any other way to do this without writing my own TCP-implementation?

Regards

Comment: Make an application level ack mechansim.

Comment: Set socket to blocking and call recv perhaps?

Comment: @Simon It would be great if I would not have to change the server code (not that simple in my case, the server is an embedded system).

Comment: @BlackBear Then the call to recv should block until I receive data from the server, but wouldn't react on the ACK, or am I mistaken?

Comment: @Jannis Froese: that's the point, I'm not sure

Comment: Be careful with terminology.  TCP is a byte stream.  If you have an app-level protocol that creates packages/packets, so be it.  But don't think in terms of network packets when using TCP.  When you talk about "Ack-Package" is this an app-level reply?  If not, abandon all hope. App has no direct visibility to TCP-level ack.

Comment: By "Ack-Package" I really mean the tcp-level ack because I need to now the time the package needed for transfer over the net on a device without ping capability. But if you say it is impossible I will have to search an other possibility.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to do the minimum implementation to achieve your goal.  In this case you should set your socket to blocking, and following the send which blocks until all data is sent, you call recv which in turn will block until the ACK packet is received or the server end closes or aborts the connection.

If you wanted to go further with your implementation you'd have to structure your client application in such a way that supports asynchronous communication.  There are a few techniques with varying degrees of complexity; polling using select() simple, event model using WSASelectEvent/WSAWaitForMultipleEvents challenging, and the IOCompletionPort model which is very complicated.

Comment: `recv()` will not unblock when a bare ACK packet is recieved - only when some actual data from the server is received (or the connection is closed).

Answer (score 0):

peudocode... Will wait until ack is recevied, after which time you can call whatever functionallity you want -i chose some made up function send_data.. which would then send information over the socket after receiving the ack.

```
data = ''
while True
    readable, writable, errors = select([socket])
        if socket in readble
            data += recv(socket)
            if is_ack(data)
                timer.start() #not sure why you want this
                break
send_data(socket)
```